# XQuery - Using computed element constructor in text

Tags: xml, xquery

In XQuery, how do I mix xml with the [computed element constructor](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#id-computedElements) to set a node's tag from a variable.

I tried doing it this way, but no luck:

```
 if ($x eq "something") then
    <cp:value>
      {element {fn:string-join( ("if:GICS", $cp/@id), "" )} {""}}
    </cp:value>
```

The expected output is:

```
<cp:value>
  <if:GICS1234 />
</cp:value>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The element-name part of an element constructor needs an `xs:QName` to produce the element name. If it is supplied a string it coerces it to a QName as if you had called `xs:QName('my-element-name').

Thus you must obey all the rules you would obey as if you had an explicit `xs:QName()` constructor in there. That means if you are using a namespace prefix (such as `if:`), it must be possible to resolve this namespace in the static context.

The simplest thing you can do is simply declare your `if:` namespace in your prolog (like presumably you declared your `cp:` namespace):

```
declare namespace if = "http://example.org/if";
element {fn:concat('if:GICS','1234') } {}

(: usually produces <if:GICS1234 xmlns:if="http://example.org/if"/> :)
```

If you don't want to do this, you can construct a QName explicitly using the `fn:QName()` function and the full namespace for `if:`. (Note `*fn:*QName` is different from `*xs:*QName`!)

```
element {fn:QName('http://example.org/if', fn:concat('GICS', '1234'))} {}

(: usually produces <GICS1234 xmlns="http://www.example.org/if"/> :)
```

If you want to control the prefix used, you can include 'if:' in the second argument:

```
element {fn:QName('http://example.org/if', fn:concat('if:GICS','1234'))} {}

(: produces <if:GICS1234 xmlns:if="http://example.org/if"/> :)
```

Note that exactly *what* prefix you get in your xml output may vary by xquery processor and by the structure of the xml you are producing, but you will always get the equivalent XML Infoset.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly have a namespace prefix in a string.  You need to create a QName containing the namespace from the namespace url.

Use something like

```
if ($x eq "something") then
  <cp:value>
    {element {fn:QName("if namespace url", fn:string-join( ("if:GICS", $cp/@id), "" ))} {""}}
  </cp:value>
```

And you can just as well use concat instead of string-join

```
if ($x eq "something") then
  <cp:value>
    {element {fn:QName("if namespace url", fn:concat( ("if:GICS", $cp/@id) ))} {""}}
  </cp:value>
```